# Render object transparent with camera instead changing object render mode

Tags: unity, c#

I have a pretty large area where I want to show the floor with 60% transparency using a so-called **Opacity camera (an idea)**. I know I [can set mesh rendering mode to transparent](https://forum.unity.com/threads/make-object-cube-transparent.495314/) and then decrease the alpha value. My question is that, is there any way available to apply mesh transparent rendering setting to my camera instead of the object.

Comment: Which render pipeline do you use?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the effect you're trying to achieve. What player-perceptible difference, or development/runtime advantage, do you suppose you would get by applying this to the camera instead of the mesh?

Comment: @Philipp I am using the built-in pipeline.

Comment: @DMGregory Maybe to see the floor structure, or see through the floor in order to view under floor objects.

Comment: @DMGregory According to my current knowledge, I don't think it is possible using camera settings only. We have to change mesh rendering mode. Therefore, I asked the question here. Maybe any answer available.

Comment: What I mean is, if you want to "see the floor structure, or see through the floor to view under floor objects" why would you not achieve that goal by modifying the floor's material? Why would you want to try to do this with the camera instead? How would that be better, in your mind? I'm trying to figure out why you wouldn't solve this in the way that you already seem to understand. There isn't really such a thing as an "opacity camera" — cameras in games are basically just a nice conceptual wrapper around a matrix, with all the real rendering work being done by material shaders.

Comment: Because I want to avoid scripting. The meshes are loading/unloading dynamically using the asset bundle.First I have to search specific object then apply specif transpacny settings.It require some programming and maybe it will not efficient